# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client while post action

Tags: node.js, express

Please help me. Where is the second response. And it creates two same data https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjx38.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

This error means you already send the response earlier with the same request and you are trying to send the response again to the client.

There must be some other code which is causing this issue.